# By validating textbox value checkbox should get disabled

Tags: javascript, html

I have one textbox and a checkbox.

What I want, when I enter value in textbox and the value is less than 999 the checkbox should get disabled.

Following is HTML and javascript code, but its not working as intended. Please help me to fix this.

HTML

```
<input name="lgnum" id="lgn" type="text" onChange="validateLoadGroupNumber()"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="field1" name="faAccount" />
```

Javascript

```
  var loadGroupNumber="0";
    loadGroupNumber=document.getElementById("lgn").value;
    alert("LGN:"+loadGroupNumber);
    if(loadGroupNumber < "900")
    {
    document.getElementById("field1").disabled=true;

    }
```

Comment: document.getElementById("1").disabled, 1 should replaced by field1.

Comment: @Jaykishan: Sorry I changed it, actually its "field1" I mistakenly added "1" but its still not working..

Comment: Can you try using jQuery, it becomes much simpler

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some things not correct in your code:

- Comparing numbers are not the same as comparing strings
- the element with id "1" does not exist
- the function validateLoadGroupNumber(obj) does not exitst

HTML suggestion:

```
<input name="lgnum" id="lgn" type="text" onkeydown="validateLoadGroupNumber(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="field1" name="faAccount" />
```

This javascript code should work better:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function validateLoadGroupNumber(obj){
try {
    if(parseInt(obj.value, 10) < 999){
        document.getElementById("field1").disabled=true;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("field1").disabled=false;
    }
}
catch(exc){
    alert("only numbers pls");
}
}
</script>
```